# Is the public data dump corrupted?

Tags: support

Currently, downloading the latest 7z archives from https://ia800107.us.archive.org/27/items/stackexchange/ gives an error that they are not valid 7z files. Is this a known issue?

Comment: Refer this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382654/issues-decompressing-the-october-2022-dump